# Creating a user in Google App Engine and migrations the easy way

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am a bit new to GAE, so I wanted to ask, how do you create a user model for something as trivial as a blog.

So, far, this is all I got:

```
class User(db.Model):  # Todo create a user model, that works with your login page
    username = db.UserProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty()
```

But this looks very primitive. How would one go about creating a user in google app engine, as in what is the best practice, of creating such fields where uniqueness is an important factor.
Also, how would you link a user to a blog post, since links are not allowed in google data-store.
Finally is there an app that manages all your migrations? Like south for GAE? There seems to be a way to migrate, but it involved a great deal of [boiler-plate code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema).

Also, I come from a django background, so I am finding all of this a little counter-intuitive, since this is not a relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` class is fine for now, you can add fields to your model as you need them during development. But you should use `ndb` rather than `db`. `ndb` handles much more features (like automatic caching). You can find more details [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/).

If you want to learn more advanced user or datastore models, you can look at `gae-boilerplate`, which already handles user login and signup (even from facebook/twitter/...). The README is very well documented :
https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

You can implement some kind of relations in your models, either by using a `KeyProperty()` or by setting a parent entity when you create one. For example :

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    content = ndb.TextProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_add_now=True)

# Then you can specify a parent in the constructor (where user is a User entity)
blog_post = BlogPost(parent=user)
blog_post.title = 'Post title'
blog_post.content = 'Post content'
blog_post.put()
```

Then use [Ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Queries) to retrieve all blog posts published by a user.

Comment: Would you mind adding a little bit of code as to how you would add a parent in this constructor? It would make the answer comprehensive. Sorry to ask again.

Comment: All the code is here, `user` is a User entity that you can retrieve from a query. If you don't know how to do it I suggest you to read the documentation about ndb queries.